# Is there any way to make UITextFieldDelegate more dynamic in swift?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I nearly have a UITextFieldDelegate in a UIViewController,and I make

```
import UIKit

class testViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var textName: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad(){
       super.viewDidLoad()

       textName.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
       return true
    }
}
```

it works very well.
but my question is, when i have two, or three UITextFields, and have different function,what should i do? Is there any way to make UITextFieldDelegate more dynamic in swift? just like java do? I remember that java may do like that:

```
textName.delegate = UITextFieldDelegate{
   func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
       return true
    }
}

textAddress.delegate = UITextFieldDelegate{
   func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
       return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate methods take a parameter that identifies the text field for which the demarcate methods are being called. You can use this to provide different behaviours for different text fields.

Comment: now i'm using "tag" property to identify the text field

Comment: Don't use tags. Use a reference to the text field instead. Presumably you already have them as outlets.